# haskell load module in list

Tags: haskell, module

Hey haskellers and haskellettes,
is it possible to load a module functions in a list.
in my concrete case i have a list of functions all checked with or

```
checkRules :: [Nucleotide] -> Bool
checkRules nucs = or $ map ($ nucs) [checkRule1, checkRule2]
```

i do import checkRule1 and checkRule2 from a seperate module - i don't know if i will need more of them in the future.

i'd like to have the same functionality look something like

```
-- import all functions from Rules as rules where
-- :t rules ~~> [([Nucleotide] -> Bool)]

checkRules :: [Nucleotide] -> Bool
checkRules nucs = or $ map ($ nucs) rules
```

the program sorts Pseudo Nucleotide Sequences in viable and nonviable squences according to given rules.
thanks in advance ε/2

---

Addendum:
So do i think right - i need:

```
genList :: File -> TypeSignature -> [TypeSignature]
chckfun :: (a->b) -> TypeSignature -> Bool
```

at compile time.
but i can't generate a list of all functions in the module - as they most probably will have not the same type signature and hence not all fit in one list. so i cannot filter given list with chckfun.

- In order to do this i either want to check the written type signatures in the source file (?) or the inferenced types given by the compiler(?).
- another problem that comes to my mind is: not every function written in the source file might get exported ?
- Is this a problem a haskell beginner should try to solve after 5 months of learning - my brain is shaped like a klein's bottle after all this "compile time thinking".

Comment: Not really. You could perhaps generate the import list programmatically from Template Haskell.

Comment: hmm - i had a look at Template Haskell and was quite overwhelmed - could you give me some hints or keywords to look for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a nice package on Hackage just for this: [language-haskell-extract](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/language-haskell-extract/0.2.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Extract.html). In particular, the Template Haskell function `functionExtractor` takes a regular expression and returns a list of the matching top level bindings as `(name, value)` pairs. As long as they all have matching types, you're good to go.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Language.Haskell.Extract

myFoo = "Hello"
myBar = "World"

allMyStuff = $(functionExtractor "^my")

main = print allMyStuff
```

Output:

```
[("myFoo", "Hello"), ("myBar", "World")]
```