# How to dynamically call a function which defined in multiple modules in the same signature

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I've defined a lot of functions (say, 100+), each of which do a specific work but with the same signature. That is something like:

```
module R001 (run) where run = <do-...>
module R002 (run) where run = <do-...>
```

What I wanna do is to provide the actual 'run' as user input, such that:

```
main = do
         runWith $ read $ getLine
       where
         runWith :: Int -> IO ()
         runWith n = R<n-padded-with-0>.run
```

Currently, I import all modules qualified, and put all the `run`'s into a list of `[Maybe (IO())]`, so this works:

```
runWith n = case Rs !! (read $ getLine) of 
              Just run -> run
              Nothing -> undefined
```

But as the `n` grows, I have to continously maintain a big list.

Is there any way I can define the big list using TemplateHaskell, or just load the corresponding module as needed at runtime without having to seperate each module into different shared libraries.

---

Based on ***epsilonhalbe***'s answer, I did some research:

```
import R1 (run1)
import R2 (run2)

test = $(functionExtractor "^run")

main :: IO ()
main = do
         putStrLn $ show $ length $ test
         run1 -- remove on second attempt
         run2 -- remove on second attempt
```

This block of code prints 2 following the results of `run1` and `run2`. If I remove the last two lines, it just prints 0. It seems that functions imported but not referenced won't be extracted ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I once had a similar problem [haskell load module in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323142/haskell-load-module-in-list) maybe this helps.

You can create a list of functions with regexp and choose a function by userinput from that list.
I don't know if you have to import all "runs" qualified by hand or if you can

```
import R*.hs (run)
```

i would rather write one file with `run1 = …`, `run2 = …` and generate a list of all runs and a function chooser function which takes a function from a list of functions with the same type signature.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Language.Haskell.Extract
import myRunFunctions

main = do
     let listOfRuns = $(functionExtractor "^run")
     putStrLn "please choose a run"
     putStrLn $ show listOfRuns
     let run = runWith $ read $ getLine
     run
   where
     runWith n = listOfRuns !! n
```

Attention: I have *not* run this code this is just a stream of thought put in haskell syntax

i hope this is helpful

---

**After edit:**
In my example i wrote all `run*` in one file and there i generated the list of all run functions, which worked instantly - have a look at my [Nucleotide Project](https://github.com/epsilonhalbe/Nucleotide) especially the files `Rules.hs` and `Nucleotide.hs`.

`Runs.hs`

```
module Runs where
import Language.Haskell.Extract

listOfRuns = map snd $(functionExtractor "^run")

run1 = …
run2 = …
```

`Main.hs`

```
import Runs

main = do
     putStrLn "please choose a run"
     putStrLn $ show listOfRuns
     let run = runWith $ read $ getLine
     run
  where
    runWith n = listOfRuns !! n
```

happy to be helpful

Comment: Thanks! this is very helpful, at least `functionExtractor` is new to me. I did some research, and updated the original post.

Comment: This is quite like QuickChekc's `prop_*`. The Haskell Test Framework `HTF` which collects all HUnit testcases/QuickCheck props in one file uses a custom preprocessor `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -F -pgmF htfpp #-}`. This is the last solution I want to use, but I'm afraid this is the only solution?

Comment: i am most definitely sure that this is not the only solution - but the best i can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Is it absolutely critical that the different `run` functions live in different modules? If you can put them all in one module, you could make `run` be a function of an `Int` (or `Integer` if you prefer).

```
module AllMyCircuits where
run 0 = {- do blah blah blah -}
run 1 = {- do blah blah blah -}
run 2 = {- do yikes -}

module Main where
import AllMyCircuits
main = readLn >>= run
```

Comment: thanks, that's my first solution. But I have to separate them at least into small compile units, so that changing to one `run` won't get others recompiled.